# Latitude/Longitude RegEx in N-S and E-W format

Tags: c#, regex

I'm asking what looks like a similar question to all the lat/lon regex questions, but my question puts a different spin on the format that I haven't been able to find.  I want to only accept a format as such:

```
LAT: XX-XX.XX N|S
LON: XXX-XX.XX E|W
```

This is for a C# window text entry where latitude and longitude are entered in separate textboxes.

I want the format to only accept 1 dash(-) and 1 decimal in those locations (i.e. negative values are invalid) and enforce the range correctly so that all place values need to be entered such as:

### LAT 0-90 North or South

```
00-00.00 N     valid
5-00.00 N      invalid
05-00.00 N     valid
90-00.00 N     valid
89-59.99 S     valid
90-60.00 S     invalid
91.00.00 N     invalid
```

### LON 0-180 East or West

```
0-0.0 E        invalid
15-00.00 E     invalid
015.00.00 E    valid
180-00.00 E    valid
180-01.00 E    invalid
179-59.99 W    valid
179-60.00 W    invalid
181-00.00 W    invalid
```

I know how to do it digit by digit such as for Latitude:
[0-9][0-9]-[0-5][0-9].[0-9][0-9] [N|S]

That is the extent of my knowledge of RegEx authoring.

As always, any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is wrong with the example regex you provided for latitude?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what's wrong, your digit by digit works well, what are you looking for ?

Comment: My very simple expression accepts the direct case with no validation such as every digit must be entered including any leading zeros(0) and in cases where minutes > 0 are not valid such as 90-59.99 N is not valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is

```
String patternLatitude = @"^(90\-00\.00)|([0-8]\d\-[0-5]\d\.\d\d) (N|S)$";
String patternLongitude = @"^(180\-00\.00)|((1[0-7]\d)|(0\d\d)\-[0-5]\d\.\d\d) (W|E)$";
```

providing that the given example

```
  015.00.00 E    valid
```

should be actually invalid. More testing examples (all invalid)

```
 090-00.01 N
 180-00.01 E
 190-00.00 E
 200-00.00 E
```

Explanation:

Latitude:
    90-00.00 is a *special case* (the only possible value with 90 degree), for other degree values we can put down `[0..8]\d`; minutes are `[0..5]\d` and decimals are just two digits: `\d\d`.

Longitude: `180-00.00` is a *special case* (the only possibility with 180 degree); the second case 1** lattitudes: since we don't have `180` or `190` lattitudes we can put them as `1[0-7]\d`; finally if a lattitude starts with 0 it can have any two digits more: `0\d\d`. Minutes and their decimals are the same as they are in the Lattitude case.

Comment: Might be a misplaced paren's there in the longitude `@"^((180\-00\.00)|((1[0-7]\d)|(0\d\d))\-[0-5]\d\.\d\d)[ ](W|E)$"`

Comment: Latitude too `@"^((90\-00\.00)|([0-8]\d\-[0-5]\d\.\d\d))[ ](N|S)$"`

Comment: @sln -- It looks like these are the only expressions that work as far as I have tested thus far.  So, along with the comment above, my vote is for this answer.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @sorton9999 - That's quite impossible because `@"^(180\-00\.00)|((1[0-7]\d)|(0\d\d)\-[0-5]\d\.\d\d) (W|E)$"` matches "`180-00.00`". Have you actually tried these ?

Comment: Yes.  The expressions in your comment work.  The answer itself does not work.

Answer (score 0):

To limit degrees to 0-90/0-180, and seconds to 0-0/59-99, I would go for these regex:

```
#Latitude:
(([0-8]\d)-(0\d|[1-5]\d)\.\d\d|90-00.00)\s[NS]
#Longitude:
((0\d\d|1[0-7]\d)-(0\d|[1-5]\d)\.\d\d|180-00.00)\s[EW]
```

Comment: I think the problem with this approach, at least for latitude, is that it would accept `90-59.99 S` which, given my understanding, should be invalid. In other words, if it starts with "90-", then every other numeric character should be "0".

Comment: It makes sense... I edited my answer to take this in account.

Comment: lattitude can't be more than `180-00.00`, that's why `180-01.00` is invalid; format is `degree-minutes.decimals` where *degrees* are in range `[00..90]` or `[000..180]`, *minutes* are in range [00..59] and *decimals* as usual are in [00.99]

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Many thanks for your explanation, my edit already fits it.

Comment: @zessx -- The longitude expression does not allow values 100 - 109 in the degrees. It doesn't allow a normally valid entry 100-00.00 E up to an entry of 109-00.00 E

Comment: `1[0-7]\d` does match the range [100..109], no?

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you a regex to match the latitudes, along with capturing groups to enable access to the degs/mins/secs and N/S values:

```
(([0-8]\d)[-.]([0-5]\d)\.(\d\d)|(90[-.]00\.00)) ([N|S])
```

And the same for E/W:

```
((0\d\d|1[0-7]\d)[-.]([0-5]\d)\.(\d\d)|(180[-.]00\.00)) ([E|W])
```

Comment: Too many leading zeros(0) are allowed in the latitude degrees.  It allows 010-00.00 N when it should be invalid

Answer (score 0):

This may be hard to look at ... but it validates.

```
 #  @"(?:(?:(?:(?:0\d|[1-8]\d)(?=-\d\d\.\d\d[ ][NS])|(?:0\d\d|1[0-7]\d)(?=-\d\d\.\d\d[ ][EW]))-(?:(?:(?:0\d|[1-5]\d)\.\d\d)))|(?:(?:90(?=-\d\d\.\d\d[ ][NS])|180(?=-\d\d\.\d\d[ ][EW]))-00\.00))[ ][NSEW]"

 (?:                                 #
      (?:                                 # =============
           (?:                                 #
                (?:                                 # LAT:  00 to 89   North or South
                     0 \d                                #
                  |  [1-8] \d                            #
                )                                   #
                (?= - \d\d \. \d\d [ ] [NS] )
             |                                    # or,

                (?:                                 # LON:  000 to 179   East or West
                     0 \d\d                              #
                  |  1 [0-7] \d                          #
                )                                   #
                (?= - \d\d \. \d\d [ ] [EW] )
           )                                   #
                                               #
           -                                   # -
                                               #
           (?:                                 #
                (?:                                 #
                     (?:                                 # 00 to 59
                          0 \d                                #
                       |  [1-5] \d                            #
                     )                                   #
                     \.                                  # .
                     \d\d                                # 00 to 99
                )                                   #
           )                                   #
      )                                   #

   |                                    # or,

      (?:                                 # =============
           (?:                                 #
                90                                  # LAT:  90  North or South    
                (?= - \d\d \. \d\d [ ] [NS] )
             |                                    # or,
                180                                 # LON: 180  East or West
                (?= - \d\d \. \d\d [ ] [EW] )
           )                                   #
           - 00 \. 00                          # - 00.00
      )                                   #

 )                                   #
 [ ]                                 #  =============
 [NSEW]                              # N,S,E,W
```

Comment: While this is an amazing expression, unfortunately it allows three digit degrees for latitude.  The latitude 020-59.00 N is considered valid.  This should not be allowed.

Comment: @sorton9999 - With anchors `@"^(?:(?:(?:(?:0\d|[1-8]\d)(?=-\d\d\.\d\d[ ][NS])|(?:0\d\d|1[0-7]\d)(?=-\d\d\.\d\d[ ][EW]))-(?:(?:(?:0\d|[1-5]\d)\.\d\d)))|(?:(?:90(?=-\d\d\.\d\d[ ][NS])|180(?=-\d\d\.\d\d[ ][EW]))-00\.00))[ ][NSEW]$"` There is no reason to use 2 expressions, combined and factored it will just be this anyway.